# How to use custom code snippets in Toad for Oracle?

Tags: oracle, toad

I'm using Toad for Oracle for accessing Oracle databases. Is there a possibility to invoke custom scripts from Toad so that you don't always have to type these from scratch? E.g. I would like to create custom script

```
select count(*) as cnt
from
```

and invoke this using custom text like

```
scf
```

This kind of functionality is found e.g in [Redgate's SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/):

> It doesn't tell you how you should write code, either. You can tell
>   SQL Prompt exactly how you like your SQL, and add your own code
>   snippets to the customizable library

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is called Code Snippets

Insert Code Snippets:
http://dev.toadformysql.com/webhelp/Content/Editor/Code_Snippets/Code_Snippets.htm

If you defined it correctly then:

> "If you know the shortcut name for a snippet, enter the shortcut name
>   and press CTRL+SPACE."

Comment: As far as I can see, code snippets only lets you insert one line, usually for function calls.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use auto-replace to solve your problem if it's a single line of text.

I use "sfr" for `SELECT * FROM`.

As soon as I type "sfr" and press space or tab, it replaces it with `SELECT * FROM`.

Go to View -> Toad Options -> Editor -> Auto Replace

Answer (score 0):

Go to view, toad options, in the sub editor you should find behaviour, click add on top right pane, and insert your preferred shortcut